# what time does reactJS reference useRef Hook variable to html element having ref attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref

I am starting learning about useRef in ReactJS. I have a question about what time ReactJS replace the **initialValue** ( *which we pass when define useRef* ) by the **Dom node** (*that contains **ref attribute***). I have run code following but result does not like what i guess :

[image]

**Before** running the code, i predict that:

*result of line 7* is ***before: {current: '1'} {current: '2'}***

*result of line 15* is ***after: {current: `<h1>Hello world</h1>`} {current: `<p>happy coding</p>`}***

And i think that at *line 15* reactJS have updated value of **refH1** and **refP** *(reactJS update value of refH1 and refP at line 10 and 11 respectively)*

**However** the result of the code is:

`before: {current: '1'} {current: '2'}`

`after: {current: '1'} {current: '2'}`

Therefore i have a question that What time does ReactJS replace **initialValue** by **Dom node** for useRef Hook?

Comment: Don't forget that console.log often uses lazy evaluation. You are also console logging as an unintentional side-effect directly in the body of a React function component, so the timing of the logs don't really correlate to what React is doing to/with the DOM. Use the `useEffect` hook to issue intentional side-effects, like logging values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs

> When React creates a DOM node for this , React will put a reference to this node into myRef.current

So it's when html element is created. Not when jsx element is created.